# If a variable equals a number goto

Tags: batch-file

If a variable equals, for example `1` then `goto` to `start1` BUT if the same variable equals `2` then `goto` to `start2`.

This is what i have so far:

```
if %method% == "1" (goto start1)
if %method% == "2" (goto start2)

:start1
echo start1
pause
exit

:start2
echo start2
pause
exit
```

But even if the `method` variable is equals `2` it always echo me `start1`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to be careful with whitespace. Write

`if "%method%"=="1" (goto start1)`

*etc* instead. You may or may not need the extra quotations around `%method%`, depending on how you've set up your envrionment variable.

Comment: You're Magical :D and Thanks very much i'll accept you're anwser when i can.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make sure that no part of those sections would execute if `%method%` doesn't match `1` or `2`. You can have `goto :eof` or just exit with `exit /b 1`.

```
if %method%=="1" (goto start1)
if %method%=="2" (goto start2)

echo Invalid method: %method%
goto :eof

:start1
echo start1
pause
exit

:start2
echo start2
pause
exit
```

Comment: Note that if you're calling this from a command prompt, hitting an "exit" will not only exit the batch file, but the entire prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Having many if statements is kind of not neat ..have a counter for your comparing if statement. This should do the trick, I guess...

```
@echo off

Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set returned_value=0

Set /p method= enter value:

: begin

For %%i in (*) do (
  Call :next_number returned_value
  If "!method!"=="!returned_value!" (
    Goto start!returned_value!
  )
)

Goto begin

:next_number

Set /a %~1+=1

: start1

echo I am start one !!

rem Other statements... etc
```

And from there you can have all sorts of functions from start1 to any point you want.

Comment: This seems pretty complicated... I don't think the OP understand this.....